# How to Improve the way to Hide/Show NavigationView menu Items?

Tags: java, android, navigationview

I was wondering how can I Improve the way that I'm handling menu item access in my app.

First of all I've a Login Activity where the users logs in and if succes it retrieves a list of all the menu items he can have access.

Then in every activity I need to run the method to hide the menu items that the user have not access.

Its called `setMenus` and the List `listaMenuMuestra` is the list obtained in the Login Activity

```
public void setMenus(List<ListaMenu> listaMenuMuestra){
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu nav_menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        for(int i = 0; i < listaMenuMuestra.size(); i++){
            try{
                int idMenu = getResources().getIdentifier(listaMenuMuestra.get(i).getIdMenu(), "id", getPackageName());
                nav_menu.findItem(idMenu).setVisible(true);
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.d("error","error");
            }
        }
```

Here's my `activity_main_drawer.xml`. By default all the items are invisible.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
            android:title="Inicio"
            android:visible="false"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ultimas"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Últimas consultas"
            android:visible="false"/>

    </group>
    <item android:title="Estadísticas"
        android:id="@+id/nav_tituloestadisticas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_insert_chart">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_torta"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_pie_chart"
                android:title="Gráfico de torta"
                android:visible="false"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_lineal"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_show_chart"
                android:title="Análisis por fechas"
                android:visible="false"/>
        </menu>
    </item>


</menu>
```

The "problem" that Im facing is that I've plenty Activities and it seems pretty odd to me to have to run `setMenus` on each Activity.

So the questions are **Is there a better way to handle menu items access with multiple activies and NavigationDrawer? Can just `setMenus` be called only once and keep these changes across all activities?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make a custom activity that extends to `AppCompatActivity` and override `onResume()` method to call your `setMenus()`.

```
class MenuCheckerActivty: AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onResume(){
     super.onResume()
     setMenus(listaMenuMuestra)
  }
}
```

Now in your normal activity, extend it to the `MenuCheckerActivity` created above.

```
class MainActivtity: MenuCheckerActivity {

}
```

Since we have overridden the `onResume()` of `MenuCheckerActivity`, the `setMenus()` function will be called whenever `super.onResume()` is called.
Haven't tested the code but pretty sure it clarifies the concept. Hope it helps.